# Python List Comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list, list-comprehension

I am learning python3 list comprehensions. I understand how to format a list comprehension: [equation, for loop, if statement for filtering], but I cannot figure out how to condense three lines of code into a single equation for the 'equation' part.

I am taking a number and adding it to itself and then taking the result and adding it to itself and so on to create a sequence of numbers in the list.

I can accomplish this by declaring x = 1 and then looping the following:

y = x + x

x = y

Can anybody help me to turn this into a single-lined equation and if possible, resources that I might study to help me with this in the future?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Python list comprehension are actually a very [simple](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), if you have your code written with a standard loop (and the loop can be converted to a comprehension). I would suggest you starting from a plain Python loop and then reword your question on what exactly is your problem.

Comment: Not always, there are plenty of examples where a tabbed loop is superior to list comprehension. IMHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm is equivalent to multiplying by powers of 2:

```
x = 3
res = [x * 2**i for i in range(10)]

# [3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192, 384, 768, 1536]
```

To see why this is the case, note you are multiplying your starting number by 2 in each iteration of your `for` loop:

```
x = 3
res = [x]
for _ in range(9):
    y = x + x
    x = y
    res.append(y)

print(res)

# [3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192, 384, 768, 1536]
```

As @timgeb mentions, you can't refer to elements of your list comprehension as you go along, as they are not available until the comprehension is complete.