# Creating a list with specific layout,section

Tags: python

I would like to create a program that as a result gives output that every even numbers from 0 to 100, including 0.

```
a = list(range(0, 101, 2))
print(a)
```

Output (even numbers)

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100]
```

The main thing is to have it in pair, inside the the list.

`[(0, ), (2, ), ... , (98, )]`

Comment: `p = [ (i,) for i in range(0,99, 2)]` - lookup list comprehensions.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52541850/python-list-comprehensions

Comment: Im sorry Prune, i do not understand. I tried do it by myself and I just ask here for any sugestions and thank to others for that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension  as follows

```
[(i,) for i in range(0, 101, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```py
a = list((i,) for i in range(0, 101, 2))
```

Not sure it's the most efficient way.